# Overwrite selected text

Tags: delete-selection-mode, overwrite

Previously when I selected text and type something or insert from buffer, the selected text would get overwritten. Now it gets appended, apparently I've change some setting. What is it?

Comment: [delete-selection-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeleteSelectionMode)?

Comment: Not sure why, but in my case sometimes `delete-selection-mode` stops working, but disabling and enabling again seems to fix it